# How to show the string type of html tag set

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

In fact, I'm doing a browse article sites, the problem is that the data I got from api content of the article is a string type of html tag set, but each article are not the same. And, there are some ng-click event in the tag collection. If I use ng-bind-html to display this data type, then, ng-click event can not be achieved.such as

```
"<p ng-click="open()">xxx</p><img ng-click="open()"/><iframe></iframe>"
```

of course an article can not only these tags, it is made by a collection of a lot of html tags.
If I use the directive, because the directive is a single example, when I click on the first article into the browser, return then browse second article, in the article detail page, the content of the article is still the first article.

Anybody knows how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) service to compile the angular directives in the template strings.

```
//directive linkFn
scope.templateString = "<p ng-click="open()">xxx</p><img ng-click="open()"/><iframe></iframe>";

element.html(scope.templateString);
$compile(element)(scope);
```

Comment: I use this method, but there is an error.Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded.

Comment: Only call it on the sub elements and not the parent or else a compile cycle is caused.

Comment: Sorry，I do not know how to do this.Could you tell me the detail?

Comment: Could you provide some more code which shows the string being inserted into the DOM?

Comment: Nothing else, just the string data type.